# Can't append firebase list data to html table because of push id

Tags: javascript, html, web, firebase-realtime-database, html-table

I tried appending firebase data to an html table, but it doesn't seem to work. The push ids might be a causing factor. Anyone with knowledge on how to fix this? Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table100-head">
<table>
<thead>
<tr class="row100 head">
<th class="cell100 column1">Staff Name</th>
<th class="cell100 column2">Department</th>
<th class="cell100 column3">Issue</th>
<th class="cell100 column4">Issued To</th>
<th class="cell100 column5">Time Reported</th>
<th class="cell100 column6">Issue Status</th>
<th class="cell100 column7">Time Solved</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
<div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
<table id="table_body">
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function() {

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDPpRA*********WOAtSlplK8g7c",
authDomain: "hotel-report-ticketing-system.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://hotel-report-ticketing-system.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "hotel-report-ticketing-system",
storageBucket: "hotel-report-ticketing-system.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "731***033376"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Hotel 
Complaints").child("Hotel Complaintsid");

rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {

var staff_n = snap.child("staff_name").val();
    var staff_d = snap.child("staff_department").val();
    var issue = snap.child("issue_description").val();
    var issue_t = snap.child("issue_to").val();
    var issue_tym = snap.child("issue_time").val();
    var issue_s = snap.child("issue_status").val();
    var issue_t_s = snap.child("time_solved").val();

    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td>" + staff_n + "</td><td>" + staff_d + "</td><td>" + issue + "</td><td>" + issue_t + "</td><td>" + issue_tym + "</td><td>" +
    issue_s + "</td><td>" + issue_t_s + "</td></tr>");
});

});
```

The firebase database snapshot

[image]

What could be my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can have:

```
var staff = snap.val();
```

and then access the props with:
staff.issue_to, staff.issue_status
Second of all, you want to select

```
$('#table_body tbody')
```

with jquery so you can append to the correct element.

Let me know if it worked.

EDIT:
Also, whenever something doesn't work console.log your variables, see if the jQuery selector is correct, see if all those values exist, and look in inspector to see if items were added to your html, but maybe they are empty because the variables are empty.

Comment: I think it has to do with how I am referencing them. The push id is a factor. I tried yours and it didn't work

Comment: var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("HotelComplaints/HotelComplaintsid");

Comment: I could only get it to work when I removed the Hotel Complaints node altogether...

Comment: Any luck yet? @heraphim